# How to restore window layout on `org-agenda-switch-to`?

Tags: org-mode

Pressing <kbd>q</kbd> in an agenda view restores the window layout if `org-agenda-restore-windows-after-quit` is non-nil. Is there a way to do the same on <kbd>RET</kbd> (`org-agenda-switch-to`)?

Comment: Is it your intention to disable `q` as a regular key in the `org-mode` buffer such that you can no longer type a heading such as `* queens and kings :qbert:`?

Comment: I don't want to do anything with `q`, just that `RET` in the agenda first close agenda and restore the window layout and then jump to the task in "other window".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the function `my-org-agenda-switch-to`:

```lisp
(defun my-org-agenda-switch-to (&optional delete-other-windows)
  "Go to the Org mode file which contains the item at point.
When optional argument DELETE-OTHER-WINDOWS is non-nil, the
displayed Org file fills the frame.
Like `org-agenda-switch-to', but respects the value of the variable
`org-agenda-restore-windows-after-quit'.
It is recommended to replace `org-agenda-switch-to' by this function (using
advice)."
  (interactive)
  (if (and org-return-follows-link
       (not (org-get-at-bol 'org-marker))
       (org-in-regexp org-link-bracket-re))
      (org-link-open-from-string (match-string 0))
    (let* ((marker (or (org-get-at-bol 'org-marker)
               (org-agenda-error)))
       (buffer (marker-buffer marker))
       (pos (marker-position marker)))
      (unless buffer (user-error "Trying to switch to non-existent buffer"))
      (when org-agenda-restore-windows-after-quit
        (org-agenda-quit))
      (switch-to-buffer-other-window buffer)
      (when delete-other-windows (delete-other-windows))
      (widen)
      (goto-char pos)
      (when (derived-mode-p 'org-mode)
    (org-show-context 'agenda)
    (run-hooks 'org-agenda-after-show-hook)))))
```

This is a slight modification of the source code of `org-agenda-switch-to`.
It will restore the window configuration if `org-agenda-restore-windows-after-quit` is non-nil.

Then use advice to overwrite the original function:

```lisp
(advice-add #'org-agenda-switch-to :override #'my-org-agenda-switch-to)
```

If you want to open the file in the same window instead of "other window",
replace `(switch-to-buffer-other-window buffer)` by `(pop-to-buffer-same-window buffer)`.

Comment: Thank you. I have a small Elisp question: is it required to use `advice-add` to replace the original `org-agenda-switch-to` function, instead of just giving this one the same name?

Comment: Advice is a more "clean" way to change the behavior of built-in functions, but your suggestion also works.
However, your suggestion will only work if the file with the new definition (probably your config file) is evaluated after the library that defines the function to be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

I think he means after selecting an entry, it splits the frame in two pieces. After some debugging, I found out the org-agenda-switch-to can be called with an "optional" argument, which instructs the function to close all other windows.

```
(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook
      (lambda()
        (define-key org-agenda-mode-map
          (kbd "RET") (lambda () (interactive) (org-agenda-switch-to t)))))
```

Note: I'm not an emacs expert.

Comment: That's not quite what I meant, @anakha: I don't want to delete all other windows, but to restore the window layout that was active before I ran `org-agenda-list`, and *then* open the task in "other window", using the standard Emacs logic for `switch-to-buffer-other-window` and `find-file-other-window`.

Comment: In that case this can probably be done with a function that uses `window-configuration-to-register` then launch `org-agenda-list`, select your entry and have another hook at `org-agenda-after-show-hook` that will save the current point/buffer, `jump-to-register` and `display-buffer` in the frame you like. If I have some time later today, I will look into it.